# How to contrast limit for HSV color space on Python, similar to napari?

Tags: python, opencv, python-napari

I would like to write a Python code to contrast limit HSV color space.

My grayscale input image is a Garfield:
[image: Garfield]

I am using napari, which is a graphical user interface for image processing. I found the output from napari application is different from my Python script:

Here is the napari output image:
[image: napari Garfield]

and I got from my Python code:
[image: Adjusted_Garfield]

From napari gui: The contrast limits are a 2-tuple where the second value is larger than the first. The smaller contrast limit corresponds to the value of the image data that will get mapped to the color defined by 0 in the colormap. All values of image data smaller than this value will also get mapped to this color. The larger contrast limit corresponds to the value of the image data that will get mapped to the color defined by 1 in the colormap. All values of image data larger than this value will also get mapped to this color.

I have tried:

```
image1 = cv.imread('Garfield.tiff', 0)
image2 = exposure.rescale_intensity (image1, in_range=(20, 230))

def gammaCorrection(src, gamma):
    invGamma = 1 / gamma

    table = [((i / 255) ** invGamma) * 255 for i in range(256)]
    table = np.array(table, np.uint8)

    return cv2.LUT(src, table)

image3 = gammaCorrection(image2, 2)
image4 = cv2.cvtColor(image3, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
image5 = cv2.cvtColor(image4, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)

cv.imwrite("adjusted_Garfield.tiff", image5)
```

Hope you can assist me with Python code on HSV contrast limit. Many thanks.